# Debugging TFS workflow with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I am attempting to step through a TFS workflow build process using visual studio. I have followed numerous guilds on how to set this up. I have attempted this with remote debugging and local debugging on TFS 2010, TFS 2012, and TFS 2013. Each of them fail to hit the breaks points set in the workflow (using their respective workflows and visual studio editions).

Currently in TFS 2013 workflow the debug output is spamming the following (repeated about 100+ times);

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Debug symbols are being loaded;

```
TFSBuildServiceHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Symbols loaded.
```

Also on every other run I get the following written to debug:

```
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal'
```

The symbols for this are not listed as being loaded.

As listed in the guide on [how to setup TFS workflow debugging](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/baruchf/2009/07/02/debugging-team-build-now-you-can/) I am attaching the debugger to the TFSBuildServiceHost.exe process. In local and remote this build agent is linked to the same TFS server. I then run the build and no break points are hit.

I have also setup the visual studio debugger to load symbols form the microsoft symbols server and store them in a local directory.

What is the definitive way to debug TFS workflows through visual studio?

Comment: I didn't quite get this to work either, but well enough for my purposes.  Execution didn't stop at my breakpoint in the xaml, but I was debugging a custom activity, so VS did end up showing me what line in my custom activity caused what exception and that was enough to troubleshoot and resolve my issue.  In any case, one thing I discovered is that I needed to run VS as an admin.  Could that be relevant to your case?  The UnauthorizedAccessException is making me think so.

Answer (score 0):

Per comments to the article to which you link above, a breakpoint must be placed prior to the Run on Agent sequence.  If a breakpoint is so placed, breakpoints within the Run on Agent sequence are also hit.

However, I found that it's difficult to find useful information.  A variable named debugInfo of type `System.Activities.Debugger.DebugInfo` appears in the Locals window, which provides some information.

Update:

It looks like variables and process params may be found in:

> debugInfo ->
>
> Non-Public members ->
>
> activityInstance ->
>
> Non-Public members ->
>
> System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityInstanceMap.IActivityReference.Activity ->
>
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.AgentScope ->
>
> Variables.

I'm guessing debugging into a custom activity would work with this method of having a breakpoint before the Run on Agent sequence and at the desired location, but I haven't tried it yet.

Also, when stepping through, one must use the Step Into command rather than Continue or Step Over, as using the latter two commands causes execution to complete rather than stop at breakpoints (at least in my setup).